Why does my script for setting column width for tables not work all the time?
I am using a script in Word to find every table with 3 columns, and then set their width accordingly. Not every table is this format, so I can't run a generic script. These tables have a question at the top that is a merged row of the cells, and then the 3 columns below have the answers and percentage breakdowns. If the question at the top is only 1 line then the script works. If the question is more that 1 line then the table columns are resized, but they are not the proper width (but they are close) .
BUT if I edit the table properties of one of the incorrect tables, the width value shown is correct. I just have to click on the 'Next Column' dialog button--without changing anything--and the columns magically pop into alignment.
I'm assuming this is a bug in Word, so my question is does anyone have another way to perform this task that might work better? My reports have about 500 tables in them, and about 450 of them are the 3-column tables I have to adjust, so automation would be so helpful!
This is the script I am using:
Sub SetTableWidthStrictly()
    Dim tbl As Table
    Dim tableRow As Row
    
    ' Loop through each table in the document
    For Each tbl In ActiveDocument.Tables
        ' Check if the table has three columns
        If tbl.Columns.Count = 3 Then
            ' Loop through each row in the table
            For Each tableRow In tbl.Rows
                If tableRow.Cells.Count = 3 Then
                   ' Set the width of each cell strictly
                   tableRow.Cells(1).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
                   tableRow.Cells(1).PreferredWidth = 332
                   
                   tableRow.Cells(2).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
                   tableRow.Cells(2).PreferredWidth = 55
                   
                   tableRow.Cells(3).PreferredWidthType = wdPreferredWidthPoints
                   tableRow.Cells(3).PreferredWidth = 81
                End If
            Next tableRow
        End If
    Next tbl
End Sub


I can't reproduce this issue - maybe there is another difference within the tables ...

Try adding:
tbl.AllowAutoFit = False

This is for disabling: Automatically Resize to fit contents


Thanks for the suggestion-it did not work to set all 3 columns though. The result is the same.

@pgrisham oh, can you also try to play around with even/odd/rounding the column widths?

Changing the numbers did not help either.  I tried many combinations.
